# JSON Response: return nested JSON

Tags: json, go, go-gin

I am trying to return a JSON response something like this:

```
c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"data": resp, "code": http.StatusOK, "status": "success"})
```

where resp contains data from a db table (struct) which I have converted to JSON.

I need to return the response in data key in this format:

`data["result"] = resp`

Sample response should look like:

```
{
"data": {"result" : ["This is a sample response"]}
}
```

The response can either be an object or a list of objects.
This is in Python format, how do I do this in Go?

Comment: *(dictionary in Python's term)*.I think it should be a `map` instead of a `struct`.

Comment: I am not sure which one to use here, map or struct. The actual resp contains data that I fetched from a db table using Gorm. Could you please provide an example? I have started working with Go 4-5 days ago only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could see it in the source of `gin`:

```
type H map[string]interface{}
```

So you could use(nested `gin.H`):

```
c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"data": 
        gin.H{
            "result": []string{"This is a sample response"},
        },
        "code": http.StatusOK, 
        "status": "success",
    })
```

Comment: Thank you sir, using nested gin.H solved my problem easily, I was worried that I have to use a strong type for every return, ughh..

Comment: @ShinoLex That is the common problem in static language like go. So when you try to read from `interface{}` you may need to use type assertion.